# Show results on a different page

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor app that gets some inputs, calculates, and displays some outputs via Edit Form and single model.

Some of the inputs:

```
<EditForm Model="@model" OnValidSubmit="hundlevalidsubmit">
    <div class="form-group">
            <label>Full Name</label>
                 
            <InputText style="width: 25%" @bind-Value="model.name" class="form-control">
            </InputText>
        </div>


<div class="form-group">
     <label>Type of Vessel</label>
       <InputSelect style="width: 25%" @bind-Value="model.typeofvessel" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Select the type of Vessel</option>
                <option value="5">General Cargo Ship</option>
                <option value="10">General Cargo Ship</option>
                <option value="15">Roll on-roll off Ship</option>
                <option value="20">Bulk Carrier</option>
            </InputSelect>
        </div>
<div class="form-group">
      <label>Gross Tonnage</label>
         <InputNumber style="width: 25%" @bind-Value="model.gt" class="form-control" />
        </div>
</EditForm>
```

I then bind the results at the end of the page with

```
<EditForm Model="@model" OnValidSubmit="hundlevalidsubmit">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">Full Name:</div>
            <div class="col text-right">@model.name</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">EEXI Value:</div>
            <div class="col text-right">@eexi.ToString("N")</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">Compliance:</div>
            <div class="col text-right">@model.compliance</div>
        </div>

    </div>
</EditForm>
```

And display them with a calculate button at the end of the page with this:

```
<EditForm Model="@model" OnValidSubmit="hundlevalidsubmit">

    <center>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input name="cbPrivacy" id="cbPrivacy" type="checkbox"> I accept Dromon Bureau of Shipping (<a href="https://localhost:44310/Privacy" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a>).
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-10 @*col-lg-offset-2*@" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-medium">Cancel</button>
            <button href="/Results" @onclick="@(() => { SendEmail(); })" style="background-color:green;" class="btn btn-primary btn-medium">
                Calculate
            </button>
            @*href="/Results"*@
            @* <p><a href="/About"  @onclick="@(() => { SendEmail(); })" style="background-color:green;" class="btn btn-primary btn-medium">Calculate</a></p>*@
        </div>
    </center>

</EditForm>
```

This is the code that does the calculations

```
@code {

public infomodel model = new infomodel();
public double eexi;
public void hundlevalidsubmit()
{
    eexi = (int.Parse(model.typeofvessel) + model.gt);

    if (eexi > 50)
    {
        model.compliance = "Yes";
    }
    else
    {
        model.compliance = "No";
    }


}
```

Now I would like to display the results on a new page (results).
Please note this is my first app so limited technical knowledge.

Comment: You really should not be using `<center>`

Comment: what should I use in order to place the buttons in the center? and what is the problem with <center>? Thanks

Comment: You should use CSS

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**
You can pass parameters to page being navigated like this, if the values are few and not sensitive and are used only in one place

```
NavigationManager.NavigateTo($“NextPage/{Value1}/{Value2}”);
```

**NextPage:**

```
@page “/nextpage/{value1}/{value2}

[Parameter]
Public string Value1 {get; set;}

[Parameter]
Public string Value2 {get; set;}
```

**Method 2:**
It involves using DI to hold  global data

Register service like this in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<DataService>();
```

In first page:

```
@inject DataService dataService;

dataService.model = new model with calculated values
```

**In second page:**

```
@inject DataService dataService;
```

Use dataService.model to retrieve values

**DataService.cs**

```
Public class DataService{
    public infomodel model{get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments!

I cannot seem to register builder.Services.AddScoped<DataService>();

Here is my programs.cs

namespace FinalExiiCalculator
{
public class Program
 {
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
 .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
 {
webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
});
}
}

Comment: You need to add name space of this class in program.cs file

Comment: i need to create a new namespace? And then how do i add the service?

Comment: Could you please let me know error or challenge you are facing while registering service, so that I can help you registering service

Comment: Thank you. 

The problem is that I do not know how to register a service. On the program.cs file, where do i paste this code? (builder.Services.AddScoped<DataService>();)

Answer (score -1):

You can use startup.cs file for DI

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();

            services.AddScoped<DataService>();
        }
```

Comment: Is this really an alternative answer? Please don't treat Stack Overflow like a chat

Comment: Yes this is complete answer, question asking user is unable to understand the solution, so I created a sample project and posted its workable code to help him understand solution

Comment: You have posted 4 solutions without any explanation. It's unclear which one is the best one. Please explain them

Answer (score -1):

This one is Blazor server-side .NET 6.0 project

**Program.cs**

```
using FinalExiiCalculator.Data;
using FinalExiiCalculator.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<DataService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();

**DataService.cs**
using FinalExiiCalculator.Models;

namespace FinalExiiCalculator.Services
{
    public class DataService
    {
        public infomodel  infomodel{get; set;} = new();
    }
}

**infomodel.cs**
    public class infomodel
    {
        public string compliance { get; set; } = "";
        public string typeofvessel { get; set; } = "";
    }
```

**counter.razor**

```
@page "/counter"

@using FinalExiiCalculator.Services
@inject DataService dataService

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;

         dataService.infomodel.typeofvessel = "My Vessel";
        dataService.infomodel.compliance = "Yes";
    }
}
```

**FetchData.razor**

```
@page "/fetchdata"

<PageTitle>Weather forecast</PageTitle>

@using FinalExiiCalculator.Data
@inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService

@using FinalExiiCalculator.Services
@inject DataService dataService

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from a service.</p>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                <th>Summary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                    <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div>
        <span>@dataService.infomodel.typeofvessel</span>
        <span>@dataService.infomodel.compliance</span>
    </div>
}

@code {
    private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post multiple answers. Instead, edit the one you posted already.

Comment: You should edit one of your answers to combine all the data from all of your answers and then delete the others.